# Нет элементов управления редактирования строк таблиц в phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Впервые нет настроек редактирования, удаления строк. В чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Права есть на эти действия?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, по умолчанию теперь эта возможность отключается, если у вас нет уникального индекса в таблице. Чтобы вернуть старое поведение, в Настройках/Основная панель/Обзор включите флажок "Show row links anyway".

Comment: апвоут, но  еще лучше, переходите в консоль

Comment: Никак не могу найти в настройках ни один из пунктов.

Comment: @Владимир А какая версия phpMyAdmin используется?

Comment: Я даже не знаю где посмотреть, но я решил добавить поле id с праймеркей.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляете в структуру int строку, например с длиной в 15 и ставите галочку при добавлении AUTO_INCREMENT или может отображаться как "A_I". И всё добавляется.